# Specify password file and shadow file to update in bash script

Tags: bash, shell

Hi i'm currently working on a bash script on ubuntu server where i have to specify the name of password and shadow file to update when adding user. I'm wondering how do you do it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `useradd`, `passwd`, `usermod` and `chage`.

Comment: how do you do that in bash script? Sorry, just started shell scripting.

Answer (score 0):

You've known `adduser` or other related command. The source code of those command may be written in C. So the simple way to know how to write it in shell script, you just need to transform C code. You can find all the things you mentioned in the question.

For me, this question is strange. Usually, shell script is used to contains a series of commands, not to solve a basic problem which is already solved.